# Google map zoom level

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a google map api from this [website](http://tips4php.net/2010/10/use-php-mysql-and-google-map-api-v3-for-displaying-data-on-map/) , thanks to the author.

Here is part of the code:

```
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });
  <?
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE ID='1'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $name=$row['name'];
 $lat=$row['lat'];
 $lon=$row['lng'];
 $desc=$row['address'];
  echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
 }
 ?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

However I'm facing a problem to adjust the zoom level , it set as 14, but no matter what value I changed , it remains the same.

I read from the comments below , someone suggest to remove this line : 
         map.fitBounds(bounds);

I removed it , but the center of map is move to other location , which I think is (0,0).

Is there any way to fix the zoom problem of this code? I tried to edit all the size though..but I'm not familiar with google map coding.

Thank you.

Comment: In the maps Javascript api you use map.setZoom( level ) to zoom

Comment: "but I'm not familiar with google map coding." --- then it is a great opportunity to read official documentation and official guides!

Comment: @zerkms Yes I'm now reading it ,and tried with many different examples.still need time to fully understand it..

Comment: @Irene Ling: we don't rush you - just read thoroughly and see that manual answers this and many other *trivial* questions.

Comment: Of course the center is at 0/0 , you set it there. Where do you want the center to be?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for your reply. Yes I know the center is 0,0.I'm now trying to set the center according to coordinates of marker.

Comment: +1 for a OP being able to say "Thank you" , not a behaviour of many GMap-related OPs as it seems

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thank you , I really appreciate all the replies and hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

with:

```
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

---

`bounds.getCenter()`  will return the calculated center of the bounds extended by addMarker()

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution , it works.I will read more documention about bounds ,still trying to understand it.Thanks again.

Comment: you may start here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds

Comment: Really thanks for your link , a great start for me,I will definitely read it .Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're setting a zoom level when you create the map, but then `map.fitBounds()` changes the zoom level to contain the bounds.

Try setting the zoom level after setting the viewport with fitBounds.

```
...
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(14);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get what's the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can pick where you want center the map:
`center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),`

Ofc, put some other numbers in place of 0, 0 - these are Latitude and Longitude.
Then you wont need the fit bounds - delete it.

And zoom: 14 will work (and any other number). Its not working now, cuz its taking the bounds, and trying to fit all the area inside these bound, and use MAX zoom possible, to show whole area.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes I just read from documentation that I can set center using google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),however I wish to set the center according to coordinates of markers, so still finding a way.

Answer (score 1):

After map.fitBounds(bounds) statement add the following statement

**map.setZoom(zoom:number)**

This will set the zoomlevel to your desired zoom level.

***Analyzing your code:***

You are initializing the map with zoom level 14 and center (0,0).
Significance of **map.fitBounds(bounds);** command is it adjusts the bounds of the map to show all the added markers which in-turn will change the zoom level. If you remove this statement your center will remain as (0,0) and zoom level as 14. If you want to set the center of the map use the following statement

**map.setCenter(latlng:LatLng)**

Thanks
B.J.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm actually trying to set the center according to coordinates of marker.